# Getting a list of all objects from Wordpress REST API

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, wordpress, api

I would like to receive a title and a link for 10 posts from Wordpress REST API.

My code is getting me only the first object in the JSON array. I'm aware that it's because [0], but I'm struggling with finding a solution to display desired values from all the objects.

```
<div class="mypanel">

       <script>
    $.getJSON('https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts', function(item) {       
        var text = `<li><a href="${item[0].link}"><h2>${item[0].title.rendered}</h2></a></li>`
        $(".mypanel").html(text);
    });
    </script>

      </div>
```

I read that probably $.map() would be a potential solution to my problem but can't figure out how to use it properly in this case.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I guess if you get all the values in your response then simply just iterate through that:

```
const perPage = 10; // 10 posts
const url = 'https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=' + perPage;
const handleResponse = items => {
  let text = '';      

  items.forEach(item => {
    text += `<li><a href="${item.link}"><h2>${item.title.rendered}</h2></a></li>`;
  };

  $(".mypanel").html(text);
};

$.getJSON(url, handeResponse);
```

Please find here for the REST API all the other arguments: [Arguments](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#arguments)

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use the pagination which comes as part of the WP api. Then iterate over that. Just add ?per_page=10 to your URL:

```
 http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=10
```

More here: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/pagination/